# Avoiding code repetition while handling exceptions

Tags: python, object-oriented, error-handling, comparative-review

For my application, I need to use two slightly different algorithms for persisting an entity:

```
def persistRandomAlias(self, alias):
    self.em.persist(alias)
    try:
        self.em.flush()
    except DBALException as e:
        if e.previous.code != 23000:
            raise e
        self.reloadEM()

        self.persistRandomAlias(alias)



def persistCustomAlias(self, alias):
    self.em.persist(alias)
    try:
        self.em.flush()
    except DBALException as e:
        if e.previous.code != 23000:
            raise e
        self.reloadEM()

        existing = self.findByNaturalKey(alias.name)
        if existing != alias:
            raise DuplicateNameException('The requested name is already taken', e)
```

The difference between them is in part of the code responsible for exception handling. I thought about putting the common code in one method, with remaining operations passed in a function that would accept exception object, like this:

```
def persistAlias(self, alias, exHandler):
    self.em.persist(alias)
    try:
        self.em.flush()
    except DBALException as e:
        if e.previous.code != 23000:
            raise e
        self.reloadEM()

        exHandler(e)

def persistRandomAlias(self, alias):
    self.persistAlias(alias, lambda e: self.persistRandomAlias(alias))            

def persistCustomAlias(self, alias):
    def exHandler(e):
        existing = self.findByNaturalKey(alias.name)
        if existing != alias:
            raise DuplicateNameException('The requested name is already taken', e)

    self.persistAlias(alias, exHandler)
```

However, I'm not sure if it is correct to pass an unused argument to a function.

I have also thought about refactoring common code into an abstract method object class, like this:

```
def execute(self):
    self.em.persist(alias)
    try:
        self.em.flush()
    except DBALException as e:
        if e.previous.code != 23000:
            raise e
        self.reloadEM()
        self.e = e

        self.handleE()
```

`handleE()` would be implemented in subclasses of the class implementing `execute()` method, and it could access exception object, or not, depending on implementation.

Should I choose one of these ideas for dealing with code duplication? Which one is better? Do you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was originally going to add this as a comment, but it works better as an answer.

Why don't you just have a variable among one of the method's arguments which determines whether to run the code for a custom or random alias by utilizing a single `if` statement?

For example:

```
def persistAlias(self, alias, custom_alias):
"""Please place relevant description here,
    The "custom_alias" argument determines whether to
    persist a custom or random alias."""
    try:
        self.em.persist(alias)
        self.em.flush()
    except DBALException as e:
        if e.previous.code != 23000:
            raise e
        self.reloadEM()

        if custom_alias:
            existing = self.findByNaturalKey(alias.name)
            if existing != alias:
                raise DuplicateNameException('The requested name is already taken', e)
        else:
            self.persistAlias(alias, 0)
```

Comment: I had a similar answer on stackoverflow, so I'll just copy my response:

 
It's not visible in the code I provided, but there are reasons for which I wouldn't pick your suggestion. First, the actual type of alias depends on user providing custom name value, or leaving it blank. The test for is_custom inside persistAlias method would be redundant, since it would be performed by the code responsible for both creating alias object and calling persist method.

Comment: Second thing is that the requested alias type (custom vs. random) will not change when running persistAlias() again as a response to the exception, which would also make the test redundant.